# Classification when my column data is string

Tags: classification, categorical-data, python, text-mining

```
ID           CAUSABAS   CAUSAIA    MP
2740.0       C509       C509       2
2770.0       C64X       C64X       2
17029.0      C921       C921       1
5015.0       C910       C504       1
5018.0       C504       C539       2
5030.0       C349       C509       2
```

This is a brief look at my data. The data has more columns. The **CAUSABAS   CAUSAIA** columns are labels, but it is a string. What kind of techniques in python I can utilize string for classifications?

I checked on online sources as well. 
Can I use `CountVectorizer` and `token_pattern=TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC` to deal with this problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classification can be understood as a linear model.

$dep. variable = \beta * ind. variables + \epsilon$

---

**Dependent variable is a string**

When the dependent variable is categorical it is a classification. When the dependent variable is numeric it is a regression. A strings can be understood as factor/ unordered categorical variable. Therefore you can use classification algorithms like Multinomial logit. If the strings are ordered categories you should sticked to an algorithm of ordered classification as ordered logit.

**One of the independent variable is a string**

Include dummy variables for each category. This only works if you have a small amount of categories. Take on category, e.g. C509, as base category and add a dummy variable for each of the other categories (C64X, C921, C910, and so on).

If both the dependent and the independent variable is a string you should do both: convert the independent variables to dummy variables and the dependent variables to categorical variables.

**To sum it all up**

[Convert the string to a factor (code in python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964451/python-convert-string-to-categorical-numpy) and continue like in other classification processes.

**Additional hint: multicollinearity**

In the first 3 of the 6 observations of your sample **CAUSABAS** and **CUSAIA** are the same. If the two variables are the same for many observations you might have problems with [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). Most Classification algorithms are not working properly if you have multicollinearity.  You can use the [VIF (Variance Inflation Factor)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) to check for multicollinearity.

Comment: Hopefully, I understand this correctly. So, the key idea is to convert the string into dummy variables. After that we can try to do a multi nominal logistic regression to classify.

Comment: It depends on what your dependent and what your independent variable is

Comment: You can also use another classification algorithm like random Forest or multiclass SVM